# Android Paging3 insertSeparators doesn't work as intended

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm try to add separators to my list e.g A, "Apple", "Anaconda", B "Boys", "Bostwana" however, `insertSeparators` doesn't seem to indicate when we are at the beginning or end.

```
adapter.submitData(pagingData.insertSeparators { before, after ->
    val afterDate = DateItem().withDate(after?.transactionDate)
    val beforeDate = DateItem().withDate(before?.transactionDate)

    if (after != null && (before == null || afterDate.toString() != beforeDate?.toString())) {
        return@insertSeparators afterDate
    }
    return@insertSeparators null
})
```

My expectations are that `before` will be null at the beginning while `after` will be null at the end of the list. But it's never null thus hard to know when we are at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a known bug on the paging3 library 3.0.0alpha10 version.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172254056